# How to identify base plans & attached offers from the in-app-billing response?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have created 2 base plans & attached 2 offers each.

I have **base Plans  & offer IDs** that are created at the play console. but those **ids are not coming** in `queryProductDetailsAsync`.

Please find attached the response, that is coming from `queryProductDetailsAsync`.

Please guide me to identify base plans & attached offers.

```
{
  "productId": "com.example.sub.t.monthly",
  "type": "subs",
  "title": "Monthly Plan T",
  "name": "Monthly Plan T",
  "description": "Monthly Plan T",
  "localizedIn": [
    "en-US"
  ],
  "skuDetailsToken": "AEuhp4JtR8QpMjj1LwdGqQ5OSQdD8C2UN_RXRTqc7Wd7yxfcfL5uADbPhRgZZu8",
  "subscriptionOfferDetails": [
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/YhhzJaYPbUwYo/3p2qjYlCBr7yAVi+XuVChW1T+DPW/pc1bm99LMZPOF5gioay8PLn13WX5gQHi5uGXQbq504gqa2GgAXREFggDlQ2dd3IAaQxtHw+w==",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 630000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹630.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P6M",
          "recurrenceMode": 2,
          "billingCycleCount": 2
        },
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 700000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹700.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P6M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan6m",
        "offer3"
      ]
    },
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/YhgD9pZz3zwV/wN3kJrOew+bA6q9dWsygmyjSOR1jj9sNTaWopZ/i8t/XLUXsU4I003dAETg/yRQ7LK56F89Obj/irk14wzGqAUlL8Nie7IW2mNU0CUTA==",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 665000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹665.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P6M",
          "recurrenceMode": 2,
          "billingCycleCount": 3
        },
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 700000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹700.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P6M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan6m",
        "offer4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/Yhg0YZn7oi2scq1mxhkMQEwokjsCp4WYG5tDPyJLYG9dXG/yCzuWWE2Zs7iP4jadYiCHgu9UgXiLzsJMPNcLatEKpi1siyJ0w==",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 700000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹700.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P6M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan6m"
      ]
    },
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/Yh2XN2LVVtX6hqozIZNcwz7C1RgS/Bl++LottEraD/t+3GUWOBQwHd023qAWhcWWqFuRzubjhkx0kLvJG/ogbtRBauN+OSjGfCZb6T6kpmBPggXnx",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 368000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹368.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P1M",
          "recurrenceMode": 2,
          "billingCycleCount": 6
        },
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 460000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹460.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P1M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan",
        "offer2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/Yhh6d6M8KBhYcDD9fDA/BrLhzVz+TGeZnz87/22GixNkJSflSa/VNDacRqN/UDTVFHsYLYEH86YhrGjMCbxQuDH2+XxIqdT7iSbxABvFDSYv",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 414000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹414.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P1M",
          "recurrenceMode": 2,
          "billingCycleCount": 12
        },
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 460000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹460.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P1M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan",
        "offer1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "offerIdToken": "AUj/YhhFXp4bhYDF2B3vqj4uvpv5+iUoqocofIGO7xxsp783RjfqTOMFpsqPzB2vPWVfD5oTKuE4LJu6SjGWuUuI1z1E1CQoUo6ixFw8",
      "pricingPhases": [
        {
          "priceAmountMicros": 460000000,
          "priceCurrencyCode": "INR",
          "formattedPrice": "₹460.00",
          "billingPeriod": "P1M",
          "recurrenceMode": 1
        }
      ],
      "offerTags": [
        "baseplan"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi Viishrut, have you figured out how to do this? I have the same problem.

Comment: No, I have created separate subs.

Comment: Have you tried utilizing the offertags for this?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. I think there is no meaning of creating multiple base plans but should create different subscription for the same like monthly, 6 months, 12 months - separate subscriptions for each instead of separate base plan.

Answer (score 0):

There are `basePlanId:String`, `offerId:String` *(only set for discounted offer)* on [Version 6.](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/ProductDetails.SubscriptionOfferDetails)